# Why Slime inspect only works with mouse click and not with the keyboard command?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, introspection, slime

I am using Emacs, Slime, and Common Lisp (SBCL). Nyxt is just the name of the [package](https://github.com/atlas-engineer/nyxt).

In the SLIME's REPL, calling a variable retrieves the following expression:

```
NYXT> history-entries-over-threshold

(#<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2903}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28D3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28A3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2873}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2843}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2813}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27E3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27B3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2783}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2753}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2723}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26F3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26C3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2693}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2633}>)
```

I can right-click in **any** part of the expression and there will be the *Inspect* option in the menu. Then, a buffer shows the list of elements and I can inspect each one of them.

Despite the successful experience with the mouse, I would like to use the keyboard. This seems to be possible since Slime has the command `slime-repl-inspect` bounded to `C-c I`. The problem is that it does **not** work for me.

After pressing the `C-c I` the prompt-buffer asks for the value to be expected. I insert the value that I clicked with the mouse:

```
Inspect value (evaluated): (#<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2903}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28D3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28A3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2873}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2843}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2813}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27E3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27B3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2783}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2753}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2723}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26F3}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26C3}> #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2693}>
 #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2633}>)
```

Unfortunately, the REPL throws an error:

```
 illegal sharp macro character: #\<

  Line: 1, Column: 2, File-Position: 2

  Stream: #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {100676A913}>
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR]
```

How can I achieve the same result of the mouse inspection using the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `C-c C-v C-i` to inspect the presentation at point, so no need to enter the value again.  You can take a look at the active keybindings with `C-h b`, then search for `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the message from the prompt-buffer is misleading, especially considering that you click in the value while using the mouse.

In order to achieve the same using the keyboard, the user needs to input the **variable** (not the value). So, after pressing `C-c I`:

```lisp
Inspect value (evaluated): history-entries-over-threshold
```

And it works, returning the same introspectable list achieved with the mouse:

```lisp
    #<CONS {1002A04127}>
    --------------------
    A proper list:
    0: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2903}>
    1: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28D3}>
    2: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F28A3}>
    3: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2873}>
    4: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2843}>
    5: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2813}>
    6: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27E3}>
    7: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F27B3}>
    8: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2783}>
    9: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2753}>
    10: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2723}>
    11: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26F3}>
    12: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F26C3}>
    13: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2693}>
    14: #<HISTORY-ENTRY {10131F2633}>
```